# Can't send a message to a specific discord server, getting code error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot send a message to a specific discord server using the servers id, I do not know the command for it, I tried something like this but it didn't work, I get an error, please help, thanks in advance!

My code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();


module.exports = {
    name: "inviteme",
    description: "inviteme",
    execute(message, args){
        var server = bot.guilds.get("serverid");
        var channel = server.channels.get("channelid");
        bot.guilds.forEach(guild => {
            guild.channels.first().createInvite()
                .then(inv => message(channel).send(`${guild.name} | ${inv.url}`));
        });
    }
}
```

The error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
    at Object.execute (d:\etc\Discord Bots\Coinflip\commands\inviteme.js:10:30)
    at Client.<anonymous> (d:\etc\Discord Bots\Coinflip\index.js:31:42)
    at Client.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (d:\etc\Discord Bots\Coinflip\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (d:\etc\Discord Bots\Coinflip\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (d:\etc\Discord Bots\Coinflip\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (d:\etc\Discord Bots\Coinflip\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (d:\etc\Discord Bots\Coinflip\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (d:\etc\Discord Bots\Coinflip\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
```

Comment: Have you tried requesting the details of the server manually via API? Seems like it's unable to get the general server information.

Comment: When I do the command on bot.on, it works, but as a command, it doesn't what is wrong, tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `bot.guilds.get("serverid");` will try to fetch the guild from a logged-in bot's cache - but in this file, you have `bot` set to `new Discord.Client();` and never logged in.

Do not log in multiple bot instances. Instead, what you need to do is grab your already logged in bot instance from the message object passed to your command, like this: `message.client.guilds.get("serverid")` - basically, use `message.client` instead of bot, or put `let bot = message.client;` at the beginning of the execute function.